# Insert or Update if Exist MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have two Tables and they are

Table Receiving

[image]

and Table GeneralInventory

[image]

My Question is How can I Insert the Data from `Receiving` To `GeneralInventory`  if the data is not the same? or if it is same the update the column `QtyPack` Of `generalinventory` sum it up.

TYSM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). For this you need a unique index or a primary key on your table, so that duplicates can be detected via index.

Then your query would be like this:

```
INSERT INTO GeneralInventory (ItemCode, QtyPack)
SELECT ItemCode, QtyPack
FROM Receiving
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
SET QtyPack = QtyPack + VALUES(QtyPack);
```

Comment: Its working sir and TYSM for it but it has no SUM on update and its not replace existing data.

Comment: Edited my answer to sum it up.